# Condition for maximum current

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current

An external resistance $R$ is connected to a cell of internal resistance $r$, then the current is maximum when:
a). $R<r$ 
b). $R=r$ 
c). $R>r$ 
d). Any other value of $R$ 
As $V= I (R+r)$, I think the current will be maximum when $R+r$ will be minimum. So, I think its 'a' because $r$ is a constant. So, the less the external resistance, the more the current. My book has answer 'b' and a couple of websites have the answer 'b' which I don't think is right.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you sure it is "maximum current" and not ["maximum power"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_power_transfer_theorem)?

Comment: @Bikash Adhikari current will be maximum when R =0 . So answer d :)

Comment: Answer (b) is correct for maximum power transfer not maximum current